# Distance between point layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, distance, road

I have a point layer with geographic boundaries of an area and another point layer with road network. I want to calculate the distance of each point of road network layer to the points of the geographic boundary and create a raster with the results.

Any ideas??

I use ArcMap 10.1

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're after. Boundaries are usually represented as polygons or lines, and road networks as lines - neither as points. Is the distance you want *along* the roads, or are you simply looking for the distance from any road point to the nearest boundary point (which may or may not be the nearest point on the boundary)? What does the resulting raster show/look like (a Euclidean Distance raster)? Do you have Spatial Analyst? Can you include a screenshot of your data, and perhaps a graphic example of what you are trying to produce?